# Is there a reply to AT+GCAP & co. to tell "I'm not a modem, go away"?

Tags: serial-port, hardware, modem, at-command, firmware

I'm working on the firmware of a device that is going to be connected to PCs using Bluetooth in serial port emulation mode.

During testing, I found out that modem-manager on Linux "helpfully" tries to detect it as a modem, sending the `AT+GCAP` command; to this, currently my device replies with something like `INVALIDCMD AT+GCAP`. That is the correct response for my protocol, but obviously isn't an AT reply, so modem-manager isn't satisfied and tries again with `AT+GCAP` and other modem-related stuff.

Now, I found some workarounds for modem-manager (see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/461962/tell-networkmanager-to-ignore-or-not-probe-rfcomm0) and thus [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2056285), in particular the [udev rule method](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2056285&p=12581391#post12581391)), but:

- they are not extremely robust (I have to make a custom udev rule that may break if we change the Bluetooth module);
- I fear that not only modem-manager, but similar software/OS features (e.g. on Windows or OS X) may give me similar annoyances.

Also, having full control over the firmware, I *can* add a special case for `AT+GCAP` and similar stuff; so, coming to my question:

*Is there a standard/safe reply to `AT+GCAP` and other similar modem-probing queries to tell "I'm not a modem, go away and leave me alone?"*

Comment: The proper response to a modem command if you are not a modem is *nothing*.  It should give up after trying a couple of times.  "ERROR" is a response to an AT command you don't implement.

Comment: @HansPassant: so, if I just ignore everything that begins with `AT+` I should be safe? Are there other modem-probing messages I should be aware of?

Comment: You should ignore everything that starts with AT, some of them don't have a +

Comment: @HansPassant: ugh, that's ugly... my protocol is text-based too, but fortunately I don't have commands that start with `AT`. Well, thank you for the advice, if you post it in an answer I'll be glad to upvote it (and accept it as soon as I'll be able to try it with the real hardware).

Comment: Surely there's a better way to wrangle Linux.  I don't know it.

Comment: @HansPassant: don't worry, I found a way to tell to modem-manager "leave alone this device", what I was looking for was just a "general" way for the device to tell "I appreciate your interest, but I'm not a modem", so to avoid platform-specific hacks. If you tell me that silence is the right answer, well, that's the answer I needed. :)

Comment: +1 for the effort you obviously have put in creating this answer, and yes silence would be the correct response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(making an answer out of the comments)

In order to indicate *I do not understand any AT commands at all* (aka *I am not a modem*) the correct response to any received AT commands should be silence.

---

In order to indicate *I do not understand this particular AT command* the correct response should be `ERROR`.

Anything between will trigger implementation defined behaviour of the entity sending AT commands. Some will possibly give up right away while modem-manager apparently is set on retrying sending the command until it gets a "proper" response.